# PHP: Reversing the order in which links are echoed out

Tags: php

```
$archiveNumber = 0;
$archiveDirectory = 'blogtext/';
$archiveHandle = opendir( $archiveDirectory );
$entryAfter;
$entry;
if( $archiveHandle = opendir( 'blogtext/' ) )
{
    while( false !== ( $entry = readdir( $archiveHandle ) ) )
    {
        if( $entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && !is_dir( $entry ) && strpos( $entry, '-subject' ) ) 
        {
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '-'.$number.'-', '', $entry );
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '-subject', '', $entryAfter );
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '.txt', '', $entryAfter );
            echo '<a href="blog/'.strtolower( $entryAfter ).'.php"> ';
            include( 'blogtext/'.$entry );
            echo '</a><br>';
            $number++;
        }
    }
    closedir( $archiveHandle );
}
```

Is there any way to reverse the order in which the links are echoed out in this function?

At the moment, the links are printed out in reverse order ( starting with -biggestnumber-name.php, and ending with -smallestnumber-name.php ). And I'd like to reverse it.

( I know that the way that I'm doing this is probably pants-on-head-retarded. You don't need to mention that. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$archiveNumber = 0;
$archiveDirectory = 'blogtext/';
$archiveHandle = opendir( $archiveDirectory );
$entryAfter;
$entry;

$toEcho=""; //A string we'll echo later

if( $archiveHandle = opendir( 'blogtext/' ) )
{
    while( false !== ( $entry = readdir( $archiveHandle ) ) )
    {
        if( $entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && !is_dir( $entry ) && strpos( $entry, '-subject' ) ) 
        {
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '-'.$number.'-', '', $entry );
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '-subject', '', $entryAfter );
            $entryAfter = str_replace( '.txt', '', $entryAfter );
            ob_start();  //Start buffering echo
            echo '<a href="blog/'.strtolower( $entryAfter ).'.php"> ';
            include( 'blogtext/'.$entry );
            echo '</a><br>';
            $toEcho=ob_get_clean().$toEcho;  //Insert the link at the begining of $toEcho, that's where we reverse the echo order
            $number++;
        }
    }
    closedir( $archiveHandle );
}
echo $toEcho;  //echo the reversed list of links
```

Note that I didn't test this, but the idea hould work.

Comment: Well, it does reverse the order of the list, so in a way, it does work.
But this method randomly removes the -number- code from the second link, thus breaking the list.
i.e. Link is supposed to be -> '-2-subject.php'
    Link is now -> 'subject.php'

I only have 3 items in the list at the moment, so I don't know if this would break other links too.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think ob_start is the reason for this weird behaviour. It must be something present before this modification.

Comment: What are the files name in your directory blogtext ?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I changed the code around a bit and it fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing them directly after read, gather all links into an array, sort that array and then iterate through it.