# PHP: Value won't increment for some reason

Tags: php

```
$blogDir = 'blog/';
$blogDirHandle = opendir( $blogDir );
$checkingFile = '';
$number = 0;
$codeNumber = '-'.$number.'-';
if( $blogDirHandle = opendir( 'blog/' ) )
{
    while( false !== ( $checkingFile = readdir( $blogDirHandle ) ) ) 
    {
        if( $checkingFile != '.' && $checkingFile != '..' && !is_dir( $blogDir.$checkingFile ) && false !== strpos( $checkingFile, $codeNumber ) )
        {
            $number++;
            $codeNumber = '-'.$number.'-';
        }
    }
closedir( $blogDirHandle );
}
```

The code above is supposed to check, if $blogDir has a file that begins with the current $codeNumber. If it does, then increment $number ( thus changing $codeNumber ), and then loop the check until there's no more files that start with the $codeNumber.
After this, I make multiple files, which are named with the new $codeNumber.

But for some reason it does not work.

If I have only one file in the directory, called -0-filename.php, it does increment the value, and the next file I create has -1- as it's prefix. But after creating the second file, it won't increment $number. It just makes duplicate-prefix-having files ( i.e. -0-filename.php, -1-othername.php, and -1-thirdname.php )

Any help?

Comment: Have you `echo`ed the file names coming out of the loop (i.e. `$checkFile`)? perhaps the `-1-` file is retrieved first, while `$number = 0` which causes `$number` to increment and then `-0-` file is retrieved and then `$checkingFile = '/blog/-0-...'` and `$number = 1` and therefore the condition will fail and your loop will end leaving `$number = 1`... just a guess.

Comment: At what point should I echo $checkFile?

Comment: I can't seem to see anything wrong here off the bat. What happens if you don't have any files inside `blog/`? Does it create the `-0-filename.php` file?

Comment: @Yaniro - I added 'echo $checkingFile;' before the if-statement, inside the while-loop, and the output was: ..-1-filename.php-1-secondfilename.php.-0-(firstfileuploaded).phpimages | ATrgin - Yes it does.

Comment: As i've said, file #1 comes up before #0 which gets your program stuck at #1.  Try getting all of the file names into an array, sorting it (by the first 3 characters) and checking the last entry for the highest number.

Comment: Is this your complete code? Are you creating any files inside the while loop such that the readdir function won't be aware of them since it has already executed? If the files are created outside this loop it should work.

Comment: @Yaniro, this should not be a problem. His script will keep looping until it finds a number that doesn't exist in any file. He's using strpos to see if the -number- exists at all. If it does he keeps trying another number. At worst it will fill in the gaps if there are any, but it shouldn't create dupes even out of order.

Comment: @davidethell, not quite, See dev-null-dweller answer

Comment: @Yaniro, I have no idea how to do that.. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Let me repeat myself, from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642032/258674): gather all files to an array and then operate on it.

Lets say your folder contains 2 files:

```
-0-filename.txt
-1-filename.txt
```

But for some reason your server is listing this directory in reversed order, so in the first iteration you are checking `-0-` but current file is `-1-filename.txt`, nothing happens, number is not incremented and `readdir` is moving to the next file that is `-0-filename.txt`. Now you have match, number is incremented, but there are no more files to read - `readdir` loop has ended and you are left with number = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
$lastNum = 0;

if ( ( $files = scandir( 'blog/' ) ) !== FALSE && count( $files ) > 0 )
{
    $lastNum = substr( $files[ count( $files ) - 1 ], 1, 1 );
}
```

`scandir()` returns a sorted array of file names extracted from the specified path.
The code then takes the last entry of the sorted array (which, provided that the files in the directory are GUARANTEED(!) to follow the above mentioned convention, will be the one with the highest number in the file name) and then extracts the second character from the file names which is supposed to be the file number indicator.

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a few days. - Where should I put that code of yours/what should I replace?

Comment: :), replace everything. this code is supposed to do exactly what you need, play with it and check it out.